# how can i get out the values from json and show them in NSLog

Tags: asp.net, ios, xcode, json, dictionary

hello i created a json String for a webservice and i want to output the name and description to show it in the NSLog. how can i do that. Heres my code so far:

```
    dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSLog(@"Results %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dic objectForKey:@"d"]objectForKey:@"Name"]]);
```

i get this error:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b50f30
```

when i make an NSLog to my dictionary i get this:

```
{
d = "{
\n  \"Name\": \"Apple\",
\n  \"Beschreibung\": \"Steve Jobs ist tot\"}";
}
```

my json string from the werbservice looks like this:

```
string json = @"{
""Name"": ""Apple"",
""Beschreibung"": ""Steve Jobs ist tot""}";
```

Comment: Your webservice is return a JSON string. The *contents* of the string is a JSON representation of a dictionary. That is, a dictionary has been serialized to a string and then that string has been serialized to its JSON representation.

Answer (score 1):

doing this kind of nested logging:

```
NSLog(@"Results %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dic objectForKey:@"d"]objectForKey:@"Name"]]);
```

is really tricky.  I'm guessing that whatever object "d" is returning isn't necessarily a NSDictionary object, perhaps a NSArray instead?

Try something like this:

```
NSDictionary * dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:nil];

// this gives the whole NSDictionary output:
NSLog( @"Results %@", [dic description] );

// get the dictionary that corresponds to the key "d"
NSDictionary * dDic = [dic objectForKey: @"d"];
if(dDic)
{
    NSString * nameObject = [dDic objectForKey: @"Name"];
    if(nameObject)
    {
        NSLog( @"object for key 'Name' is %@", nameObject );
    } else {
        NSLog( @"couldn't get object associated with key 'Name'" );
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"couldn't get object associated with key 'd'") );
}
```

And see if it helps you figure out at which level and at which object your assumptions are breaking.

Comment: +1, but there's little reason to invoke `-description` yourself when logging an object. That's what the "%@" format specifier already does. Just do `NSLog(@"Results %@", dic);`.  By the way, it's also possible that `dic` is not a dictionary, just like it's possible that `[dic objectForKey:@"d"]` is not.

Comment: Yep. Old habits die hard on me (i.e. calling "`description`" on NSArray & NSDictionary objects), but I do know that sending objects to a "`%@`" NSLog format specifier will print out the description of the thing.  The idea here is for Eray to find out which part of his JSON output doesn't match what his assumptions (that everything's a NSDictionary) are.

Comment: when the program goes to  NSString * nameObject = [dDic objectForKey: @"Name"]; it gets the error

Comment: Could you tell what kind of object you're really getting there (and what it's contents are)?

Comment: the dictionary description output is: Results {
    d = "{
\n  \"Name\": \"Apple\",
\n  \"Beschreibung\": \"Steve Jobs ist tot\"}";
}